# Style a SearchView widget using support library v21

Tags: android, searchview, android-5.0-lollipop, material-design

Chris Banes mentioned [here](https://chris.banes.me/2014/10/17/appcompat-v21/#searchview) that the AppCompat library now has Lollipop's updated SearchView API.  I am following the instructions straight from the blog post, but I don't see any effect.

Below is a snippet from my `values/styles.xml`

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/color_primary</item>

    <item name="searchViewStyle">@style/CustomSearchViewStyle</item>
</style>
<style name="CustomSearchViewStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.SearchView">
    <item name="queryBackground">@color/orange</item>
    <item name="searchIcon">@drawable/test</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I was using `android.widget.SearchView` instead of `android.support.v7.widget.SearchView`.  I am guessing that only the `android:*` styles work with `android.widget.SearchView`.